# C# Using new[]

Tags: c#, new-operator

I have a question about using `new[]`.

Imagine this:

```
Object.SomeProperty = new[] {"string1", "string2"};
```

Where SomeProperty expects an array of strings.

I know this code snippet will work. But i want to know what it does under the hood. Does `new[]` makes an instance of the class `object` and in `SomeProperty` it converts it automatically to a `string` object?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay, there's still a *little* bit of confusion here.

The inference that's going on has nothing to with the type of Object.SomeProperty, but everything to do with the types of the expressions in the array initializer. In other words, you could do:

```
object o = new[] { "string1", "string2" };
```

and o would still be a reference to a string array.

Basically, the compiler looks at an expression like this:

```
new[] { A, B, C, D, ... }
```

(where A, B, C, D etc are expressions) and tries to work out the correct array type to use. It only considers the types of A, B, C and D (etc) as the array element type. Taking this set of candidate types, it tries to find one which all the others can be implicitly converted to. If there's not *exactly one* such type then the compiler will complain.

So for example:

```
new[] { new Form(), new MemoryStream() }
```

will not compile - neither `MemoryStream` nor `Form` is convertible to the other. However:

```
new[] { GetSomeIDisposable(), new MemoryStream() }
```

will be treated as an `IDisposable[]` because there's an implicit conversion from `MemoryStream` to `IDisposable`. Likewise:

```
new[] { 0, 1, 3.5 } // double[]
new[] { 1, 3, 100L } // long[]
```

Answer (score 15):

This is just syntactical sugar. The compiler will infer the type actually necessary here and create code that is equivalent to the explicit construct:

```
Object.SomeProperty = new string[] {"string1", "string2"};
```

There's no such thing as `new[]` that gets executed at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

It is roughly translated to:

```
string[] $temp = new string[2];
$temp[0] = "string1";
$temp[1] = "string2";
Object.SomeProperty = $temp;
```

Interestingly, `var x = new[] { "string1", "string2" };` works as well, it can infer x to be a `string[]`, but `var x = { "string1", "string2" };` fails.

Comment: That's because an array is a reference type that must be allocated with new. Nothing is going to syntactically sugar that away.

Comment: Yes, but when given a type, the non `new[]` syntax news up the type, passing the IEnumerable<T>, so when it only has var, why couldn't it last ditch default to T[]?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler replaces:

```
Object.SomeProperty = new[] {"string1", "string2"};
```

with:

```
Object.SomeProperty = new string[] {"string1", "string2"};
```

Comment: Object.SomeProperty = {"string1", "string2"};
Not in any C# compiler I have ever seen! You can only do that during initialization.

Comment: initialization, being variable initialization. eg. string[] foo = {"bar","baz"};

Answer (score 1):

I do hope from your response you're not getting confused between type substitution and type inference here! I'm assuming the type of Object.SomeProperty is string[], though due to array covariance it could be object[] (note this would *not* be a good thing - check out [Eric Lippert's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx) on this subject!).

The compiler performs type inference using a heuristic - it determines that "string1" and "string2" are of type string, and therefore it effectively replaces your code with:-

```
Object.SomeProperty = new string[] {"string1", "string2"};
```

It really is as simple as that! It's all done at compile time, nothing at run time.